# In firebase, After deleting an APP, how can take it with the same name?

Tags: firebase

In firebase, I deleted an APP URL. After I want to take it with the same name. But I can not take it. it is warning "*This Firebase URL is not available*".

Answer (score 0):

Before you delete an app, you get this warning:

> Caution, **this is a permanent action**. Once you delete a Firebase, you cannot get it back. The URLs associated with this app will no longer be available.

That should really say it all: once you delete an app, the name is lost forever. It cannot be reclaimed.